# Force Clang to actually pass struct by value (no byval)

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

Consider the following code:

```
struct A {
    int a;
    double b;
    int c;
};

extern "C" void fn(A a) {
    // do something with a
}
```

Clang compiles this to the following LLVM code (only relevant parts shown):

```
%struct.A = type { i32, double, i32 }

define void @fn(%struct.A* byval align 8) #0 {
  ret void
}
```

In order to interface a special binary interface, I would need the signature of `@fn` to be like

```
void @fn(%struct.A)
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

clang follows the platform ABI here and how the actual lowering of arguments is implemented. So in general, no, you cannot expect arbitrary things like in your example.